# How to increase the name of a new form when opening a new child form

Tags: c#, winforms, parent-child, mdiparent

[How do you change the text in the Titlebar in Windows Forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104175/how-do-you-change-the-text-in-the-titlebar-in-winforms)

When I open a new form I want it to say "Bob, the next time i click new and open a form it should say "Bob1"
I tried to use TryParase() it to string and that wont work.

```
private void newToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 childform2 = new Form2();
        decimal childcount;
       childform2.MdiParent= this;
       string menuname;
       menuname = "untilted" + childcount.ToString();
        childform2.Text = menuname;
        childform2.Show();
        childcount++;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep `childcount` around longer than just that method.  Since you declare it inside the method, it will reset to `0` each time you run this code.  Declare the variable outside of the method, so something like this:

```
int childcount=1;
private void newToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Form2 childform2 = new Form2();

   childform2.MdiParent= this;
   string menuname;
   menuname = "untilted" + childcount.ToString();
   childform2.Text = menuname;
   childform2.Show();
   childcount++;
}
```