# How can I get the Window title of the current application/form?

Tags: c#

I have a windows application with only 1 form. Is there a way to retrieve the window title of this form (when it's running)?

Comment: Did you try `this.Text?`

Comment: Please add some details to your question. Do you mean a form of another application or do you mean your own form?

Comment: @LarsTech That's what I wanted... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're using WinForms, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104175/how-do-you-change-the-text-in-the-titlebar-in-windows-forms).

If you're using WPF, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28437096/how-do-i-programmatically-change-the-title-in-a-wpf-window).

Since you asked about C#, you're probably NOT using the Windows SDK. But if you are, then see [this page](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/C-Getting-the-Windows-da1bd524).